# How do I connect a vibration sensor/switch to a breadboard?

Tags: sensors

I have the following vibration sensor:

[image: Vibration Sensor]

It has one short/firm-er terminal and one long/flimsy terminal.  Now the shorter terminal slides easily into my breadboard but the flimsy one clearly does not.  A few related questions:

1) How do I go about connecting this to my breadboard (simply plugging it in doesn't work)?  Do I have to solder a wire onto the flimsy end?

2) Why is this switch manufactured this way (with a flimsy end)?

3) Is it right to assume that the longer end is positive (+) and the shorter end is negative (-)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from this information source:
http://www.electrodragon.com/product/vibration-switch-sensor-sw-18020p/
that the sensor is an electrical contact on the firmer side surrounded by a very sensitive spring within the enclosure. The coil spring is by design made of a smaller diameter wire to provide sensitivity to movement. Rather than manufacture a translation to a heavier piece of material, the thinner lead is brought out of the enclosure.

I suspect that it will not work on your breadboard, due to the flimsy end being too small to make solid contact within the breadboard. You could resolve that aspect by soldering on a heavier segment.

Because it is designed as a simple switch, there is no plus or minus.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  I soldered the flimsy end, plugged everything into a breadboard and now I'm getting a whole bunch of readouts.  I guess now I'm trying to figure out how to set certain thresholds but the numbers are all over the place.

Comment: From the information sheet, it appears that the spring will continue to contact the center post with a frequency based on the magnitude of the vibration. If one considers this to be a push button switch, it has a serious problem with debounce. Perhaps adding a debounce segment of code to your program will help?